# JMeter load-testing : ClassNotFoundException: com.blazemeter.jmeter.threads.concurrency.ConcurrencyThreadGroup

Tags: java, exception, jmeter, load-testing, distributed

I'm trying non-GUI and distributed JMeter load-testing.

Before I go distributed, I tested it locally. I installed JMeter on my laptop and setup a testplan targeting the system under test. I installed the plugin manager and install the concurrent thread plugin.
I found my JMX file to be correct and working, so I decided to rollout the distributed setting.

I setup three machines for load generation : load-1, load-2 and load-3. I installed JMeter as follow :
`apt update ; apt upgrade` on all of them
`apt install jmeter` on all of them
copied the JARs located in /usr/share/jmeter/lib/ext of my laptop to all of them, in the same directory :

```
jmeter-plugins-casutg-2.1.jar
jmeter-plugins-cmn-jmeter-0.3.jar
jmeter-plugins-manager-0.11.jar
```

I started the JMeter server on two of them as follow :

```
export JMETER_HOME=/usr ; $JMETER_HOME/bin/jmeter-server -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=207.112.137.21
export JMETER_HOME=/usr ; $JMETER_HOME/bin/jmeter-server -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=207.112.137.22
```

I use the third one to start the distributed testing as follow :

```
jmeter -n -t ~/JMeter_API_TestPlan.jmx -R207.112.137.21,207.112.137.22
```

The distrubuted setting seems to start correctly, but the thread start fail probably because of a class not being found :

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.blazemeter.jmeter.threads.concurrency.ConcurrencyThreadGroup (no security manager: RMI class loader disabled)

A I missing a JAR or a configuration parameter ?

The jmeter.log shows the following :

```
2017/06/23 09:34:33 INFO  - jmeter.util.JMeterUtils: Setting Locale to en_US 
2017/06/23 09:34:33 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: Loading user properties from: /usr/share/jmeter/bin/user.properties 
2017/06/23 09:34:33 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: Loading system properties from: /usr/share/jmeter/bin/system.properties 
2017/06/23 09:34:33 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: Copyright (c) 1998-2014 The Apache Software Foundation 
2017/06/23 09:34:33 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: Version 2.11.20151206 
2017/06/23 09:34:33 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: java.version=1.8.0_131 
2017/06/23 09:34:33 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: java.vm.name=OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 
2017/06/23 09:34:33 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: os.name=Linux 
2017/06/23 09:34:33 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: os.arch=amd64 
2017/06/23 09:34:33 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: os.version=4.4.0-64-generic 
2017/06/23 09:34:33 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: file.encoding=ANSI_X3.4-1968 
2017/06/23 09:34:33 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: Default Locale=English (United States) 
2017/06/23 09:34:33 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: JMeter  Locale=English (United States) 
2017/06/23 09:34:33 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: JMeterHome=/usr/share/jmeter 
2017/06/23 09:34:33 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: user.dir  =/usr/share/jmeter/lib/ext 
2017/06/23 09:34:33 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: PWD       =/usr/share/jmeter/lib/ext 
2017/06/23 09:34:33 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: IP: 127.0.1.1 Name: load-srv-1 FullName: load-srv-1.localdomain 
2017/06/23 09:34:33 INFO  - jmeter.services.FileServer: Default base='/usr/share/jmeter/lib/ext' 
2017/06/23 09:34:33 INFO  - jmeter.services.FileServer: Set new base='/home/ubuntu' 
2017/06/23 09:34:33 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: Loading file: /home/ubuntu/JMeter_API_TestPlan.jmx 
2017/06/23 09:34:33 INFO  - jmeter.save.SaveService: Testplan (JMX) version: 2.2. Testlog (JTL) version: 2.2 
2017/06/23 09:34:33 INFO  - jmeter.save.SaveService: Using SaveService properties file encoding UTF-8 
2017/06/23 09:34:33 INFO  - jmeter.save.SaveService: Using SaveService properties version 2.6 
2017/06/23 09:34:33 INFO  - jmeter.save.SaveService: Using SaveService properties file version 1554411 
2017/06/23 09:34:33 INFO  - jmeter.save.SaveService: All converter versions present and correct 
2017/06/23 09:34:33 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.control.CookieManager: Settings: Delete null: true Check: true Allow variable: true Save: false Prefix: COOKIE_ 
2017/06/23 09:34:33 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase: Cannot find .className property for htmlParser, using default 
2017/06/23 09:34:33 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/html is  
2017/06/23 09:34:33 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for application/xhtml+xml is  
2017/06/23 09:34:33 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for application/xml is  
2017/06/23 09:34:33 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/xml is  
2017/06/23 09:34:33 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/vnd.wap.wml is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.RegexpHTMLParser 
2017/06/23 09:34:33 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: Creating summariser <summary> 
Creating summariser <summary>
Created the tree successfully using /home/ubuntu/JMeter_API_TestPlan.jmx
Configuring remote engine for 207.112.137.21
2017/06/23 09:34:33 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: Configuring remote engine for 207.112.137.21
Using remote object: UnicastRef [liveRef: [endpoint:[207.112.137.21:33454](remote),objID:[-48d954a6:15cd4392e27:-7fff, 7098811430065264906]]]
Configuring remote engine for 207.112.137.22
2017/06/23 09:34:33 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: Configuring remote engine for 207.112.137.22
Using remote object: UnicastRef [liveRef: [endpoint:[207.112.137.22:39449](remote),objID:[-238f015b:15cd4393abf:-7fff, 6897427020325789391]]]
Starting remote engines
2017/06/23 09:34:33 INFO  - jmeter.JMeter: Starting remote engines 
Starting the test @ Fri Jun 23 09:34:33 UTC 2017 (1498210473781)
2017/06/23 09:34:33 INFO  - jmeter.engine.ClientJMeterEngine: running clientengine run method 
2017/06/23 09:34:33 INFO  - jmeter.engine.util.CompoundVariable: Note: Function class names must contain the string: '.functions.' 
2017/06/23 09:34:33 INFO  - jmeter.engine.util.CompoundVariable: Note: Function class names must not contain the string: '.gui.' 
2017/06/23 09:34:33 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.SampleEvent: List of sample_variables: [] 
2017/06/23 09:34:33 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.BatchSampleSender: Using batching (client settings) for this run. Thresholds: num=100, time=60000 
2017/06/23 09:34:33 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.DataStrippingSampleSender: Using DataStrippingSampleSender for this run 
2017/06/23 09:34:34 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.BatchSampleSender: Using batching (client settings) for this run. Thresholds: num=100, time=60000 
2017/06/23 09:34:34 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.DataStrippingSampleSender: Using DataStrippingSampleSender for this run 
2017/06/23 09:34:34 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.BatchSampleSender: Using batching (client settings) for this run. Thresholds: num=100, time=60000 
2017/06/23 09:34:34 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.DataStrippingSampleSender: Using DataStrippingSampleSender for this run 
2017/06/23 09:34:34 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.BatchSampleSender: Using batching (client settings) for this run. Thresholds: num=100, time=60000 
2017/06/23 09:34:34 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.DataStrippingSampleSender: Using DataStrippingSampleSender for this run 
2017/06/23 09:34:34 ERROR - jmeter.engine.ClientJMeterEngine: Error in rconfigure() method java.rmi.ServerException: RemoteException occurred in server thread; nested exception is: 
    java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is: 
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.blazemeter.jmeter.threads.concurrency.ConcurrencyThreadGroup (no security manager: RMI class loader disabled) 
2017/06/23 09:34:34 INFO  - jmeter.engine.ClientJMeterEngine: Interrupting RMI Reaper 
Error in NonGUIDriver org.apache.jmeter.engine.JMeterEngineException: Error in rconfigure() method java.rmi.ServerException: RemoteException occurred in server thread; nested exception is: 
    java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is: 
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.blazemeter.jmeter.threads.concurrency.ConcurrencyThreadGroup (no security manager: RMI class loader disabled)
2017/06/23 09:34:34 ERROR - jmeter.JMeter: Error in NonGUIDriver org.apache.jmeter.engine.JMeterEngineException: Error in rconfigure() method java.rmi.ServerException: RemoteException occurred in server thread; nested exception is: 
    java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is: 
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.blazemeter.jmeter.threads.concurrency.ConcurrencyThreadGroup (no security manager: RMI class loader disabled)
    at org.apache.jmeter.engine.ClientJMeterEngine.runTest(ClientJMeterEngine.java:156)
    at org.apache.jmeter.JMeter.runNonGui(JMeter.java:831)
    at org.apache.jmeter.JMeter.startNonGui(JMeter.java:733)
    at org.apache.jmeter.JMeter.start(JMeter.java:392)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.jmeter.NewDriver.main(NewDriver.java:259)
Caused by: java.rmi.ServerException: RemoteException occurred in server thread; nested exception is: 
    java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is: 
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.blazemeter.jmeter.threads.concurrency.ConcurrencyThreadGroup (no security manager: RMI class loader disabled)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:377)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:683)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.exceptionReceivedFromServer(StreamRemoteCall.java:276)
    at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(StreamRemoteCall.java:253)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:162)
    at org.apache.jmeter.engine.RemoteJMeterEngineImpl_Stub.rconfigure(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.jmeter.engine.ClientJMeterEngine.runTest(ClientJMeterEngine.java:133)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is: 
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.blazemeter.jmeter.threads.concurrency.ConcurrencyThreadGroup (no security manager: RMI class loader disabled)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:337)
```

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `jmeter-plugins-cmn-jmeter-0.3.jar` should go to "lib" folder, not to "lib/ext"
2. You are using JMeter 2.11 which is 3+ years old, I would recommend upgrading to [JMeter 3.2](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/whats-new-jmeter-32) (or later) by manually downloading it from [JMeter downloads page](http://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi). Ubuntu repositories seem to contain very outdated JMeter's version
3. To avoid any issues with plugins manual installation I would suggest installing the same plugins set on the master host and all the slaves using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/)