# JMeter Load Testing with Concurrency : RMI Class Loader Disabled

Tags: java, jmeter

While running the distributed load testing using concurrency thread group from blazemeter, I getting the error : "Error in rconfigure() method java.rmi.ServerExeption...java.ClassNotFoundExeption:com.Blazemeter.jmeter.threads.concurrency.ConcurrencyThreadgroup(no Security manager: RMI Class Loader disabled)

I have researched on the net and the only related issue I found is this one:

[JMeter load-testing : ClassNotFoundException: com.blazemeter.jmeter.threads.concurrency.ConcurrencyThreadGroup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44720639/jmeter-load-testing-classnotfoundexception-com-blazemeter-jmeter-threads-conc)

Unlike this thread, I have the latest version 3.3 on my machines. The jmeter logs are as follows:

> ```
> 2018-01-22 17:03:50,749 INFO o.a.j.e.DistributedRunner: Configuring remote engine: 10.0.104.58 2018-01-22 17:03:50,764 INFO
> ```
>
> o.a.j.e.DistributedRunner: Starting remote engines 2018-01-22
>   17:03:50,764 INFO o.a.j.e.DistributedRunner: Starting the test @ Mon
>   Jan 22 17:03:50 EST 2018 (1516658630764) 2018-01-22 17:03:50,764 INFO
>   o.a.j.e.ClientJMeterEngine: running clientengine run method 2018-01-22
>   17:03:50,780 INFO o.a.j.s.StandardSampleSender: Using
>   StandardSampleSender for this test run 2018-01-22 17:03:50,780 INFO
>   o.a.j.s.StandardSampleSender: Using StandardSampleSender for this test
>   run 2018-01-22 17:03:50,827 ERROR o.a.j.e.ClientJMeterEngine: Error in
>   rconfigure() method java.rmi.ServerException: RemoteException occurred
>   in server thread; nested exception is:    java.rmi.UnmarshalException:
>   error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is: 
>     java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.blazemeter.jmeter.threads.concurrency.ConcurrencyThreadGroup (no
>   security manager: RMI class loader disabled) 2018-01-22 17:09:10,937
>   INFO o.a.j.e.DistributedRunner: Remote engines have been started

Pleas let me know how to overcome this issue. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error indicate you are using [Concurrency Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ConcurrencyThreadGroup/) which wasn't found in one of your slaves. Your JMeter version should be equal to master which is the first rule of [distributed load testing](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html):

> **Step 0: Configure the nodes**
>
> Make sure that all the nodes (client and servers) :
>
> > are running exactly the same version of JMeter.

Comment: Perfect. All I needed to add the concurrency thread group on the slave and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jmeter-taurus, adding these to the [Jmeter Executor](https://gettaurus.org/docs/JMeter/) did the trick:

```
modules:
  jmeter:
    force-ctg: true   
    detect-plugins: true
```

Although the documentation said it is enabled by default, somehow that wasn't the case for one of my worker servers, this forced it to install the required Concurrency Thread Group(ctg) plugin.